# Django URL Aliases

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new to Django and I have a BIG problem. I don't like the "url pattern" philosophy of Django.

I don't want my pages to look like 
http://domain.com/object/title-of-object
I want
http://domain.com/title-of-object
and of course I will have more than one type of object.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this with Django (not using hard-coded urls)?

Thanks!

Comment: @César So _this_ is the guy who owns http://domain.com! (PS, he's referring to the url syntax, not the page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You'll have to create one catch-all URL pattern, for which you'll create a view that will search all possible object types, find the matching one, and process and return that. Usually, this is a bad idea.

Comment: I thought of that and also think it's a bad idea.

Comment: In the end I had to choose between this solution or automatically updating urls.py everytime a new object gets put in the database. I have chosen this solution. Let's see how I will get in trouble. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this is a bad idea... let's assume we have many pages, like in a CMS. I find it hard to belief that I'll need 20 views to handle those pages. My experience is that 1 view is in fact enough. So, in that scenario I'll end up with 1 view. And if that view is handling it via: site.com/view/foo or through site.com/view from a point of view of performance doesn't make any diff. the only thing is that application bar (site.com/bar) should NOT be affected by the resolvement of foo. But hey, that's why there is presedence in urls.py so... it's just a catch all at the bottom ..IMHO

Comment: @Paul: CMS pages are all pages, so they'd be handled by the same view. What OP apparently wants is the equivalent of having http://stackoverflow.com/django-url-aliases for this question and http://stackoverflow.com/Paul for your user page.

Comment: Frankly I can't believe that this is not "mainstream" functionality. It's not something weird at all. It's standard functionality throughout the PHP CMS world and it's not because "pages are all pages". You have multiple "content types" in Drupal for example. But hey, nobody said Django is perfect. I love it anyway...

Comment: It doesn't seem like a bad idea for Facebook nowadays and, considering how big it is, perhaps you mind as well have a shift of mind? Simplifying url for the sake of easier sharing forms seems just about the way to go about any serious, pretending-to-be-scalable social network nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Ever wondered that, if what you want to do seems so hard to acheive, you're doing it wrong? What is so wrong with /foo/name-of-foo/ ?

I'm trying to imagine your use-case and wondering if you need 'human' URLs for only a handful of pages. If so, it would work to go with the /foo/slug-for-foo/ approach but then use the [django.contrib.redirects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/) app to support hand-written URLs that redirect to the saner, more RESTful ones?

Comment: Sorry, I'm NOT doing it wrong. First, there is SEO and second, the /foo/name-of-foo looks really stupid

Comment: I've been thinking hard about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441382/django-url-aliases and still can't come up with why it's stupid to have "questions" in that URL. But it may be a matter of personal taste.

Comment: If anything, your approach will have a negative effect on SEO as the object type puts you page in context. If you are looking for help on a website, it's a good idea not to act do dismissive of the people trying to help you. This isn't a problem with django, it's a problem with your understanding - how can you have an url scheme that just guesses the type of operation you want to carry out (in this case displaying an object on a particular type)

Comment: Ok, forget it. It's obvious you guys don't know SEO. You could have answered 'there is no elegant way', instead of dismissing my question. I may not know Django yet but I sure do know SEO and trust me that sometimes that extra word in the beginning of the url makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: from a drupal developer now working on a django website, i find the lack of URL aliasing feature a big missing piece. this is my current problem right now.

Comment: @bonbon does django.contrib.redirects not do enough?